# Does solid aluminum oxide conduct oxide ions at high temperatures?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry

Can alumina behave as a solid electrolyte for oxygen ions? Could a cell be constructed with an oxygen cathode and a molten aluminum anode producing more alumina? Would the resulting alumina deposit on the electrolyte? Would it be crystalline?

Answer (score 2):

Alumina is one of the most abundant compounds on Earth. If it would be also a solid electrolyte for oxygen ions, why in the world would anyone go into the trouble of dealing with the whole [$\ce{Y2O3/ZrO2}$ thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yttria-stabilized_zirconia#Effect_of_stabilization_of_ionic_conductivity)? No, alumina doesn't and can't behave like that. Its oxygen ions are held in place pretty tightly.

Some forms of alumina may serve as [conductors of $\ce{Na+}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_ion_conductor#beta-Alumina) and similar cations, but that's another story.

Comment: You might use use yttria-stabilized zirconia because alumina is a _poor_ ionic conductor. Ice is a proton conductor, but nobody uses it as such. Ionic conductivity increases with temperature. The melting point of alumina is over 2000°C. Are you sure there's no ionic conduction?

Comment: Why, there might be some, just not enough to make a real thing out of it. I should have said "_If it would be also a **good** solid electrolyte..._"

Comment: If you read my question carefully, you'll note that I never asked if alumina is a _good_ solid electrolyte, only if it _is_ one. The popularity of zirconia and ceria based electrolytes in SOFCs proves it doesn't make for a practical electrolyte if the intent is to generate electricity.

Comment: Hm... that's right. It turns out that in fact I answered another question, albeit somewhat related to yours. Well, let it remain this way.